# Magento 2 : Add discount and tax in order programmatically

Tags: magento2, orders, controllers, tax

I used below link to place an order, but in that, I cannot get any solution. how to add the tax or discount in order so anyone has done this thing?

please help to solve this issue.

http://www.blogtreat.com/programmatically-create-new-order-in-magento-2%EF%BB%BF/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I have share code to apply tax in your custom code:

```
$subTotal = 121;
$taxRate = .0825;
$taxAmount = $subTotal * $taxRate;
$shippingAmount = 15;
$totalAmount =  $subTotal + $taxAmount + $shippingAmount;

$order->setSubtotal($subTotal);
$order->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal);
$order->setGrandTotal($totalAmount);
$order->setBaseGrandTotal($totalAmount);
$order->setTaxAmount($taxAmount);
$order->setDiscountAmount(0);
```

If you found answer useful please accept it.

Comment: I tried this code but the discount code value did not into order.

Comment: have you tried to "$order->setDiscountAmount(0);" change amount in this code?

Comment: yes, I tried your code and it is working. thanks

Comment: @P_U, how to add tax amount for quote item? here is my question regarding it, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart

Comment: You saved my day, I can confirm it is working correctly in Magento 2.4.1. Thanks man